# Replace hsqldb with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, maven

I have a Spring REST project configured with hsqldb.
I would like to change it to MySQL. 
I have MySQL server installed and running, but I don't know how to modify this pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

PS.: Project im talking about comes as a source code for 'Spring REST' book:
http://www.apress.com/9781484208243

source code download link:

http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1704/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I see you are using Spring Boot on this, so you can easy change the databases changing the drivers dependencies from:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

To

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The driver version will be version on parent pom.
Then specify the parameters on properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/yourdb
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver # we can ommit this if we want, Spring Boot will deduce based on the classpath
```

For more configuration on databases you can see the properties available on appendix [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Thanks dude, you made my day!