# Add Hibernate to SpringBoot project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a simple Spring Boot project (already mentioned here: [Replace hsqldb with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185044/replace-hsqldb-with-mysql))

I would like to configure Hibernate to work  with this project. In another project I used to get EntityManager like so:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "orm-unit")
private EntityManager em;
```

but there I also have persistence.xml with required configuration.

In Spring Boot I don't even know where to place any configuration files.
How to make Hibernate work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Spring Boot documentation. Looking over [31. Working with SQL databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-configure-datasource)   you will see that you need to configure a DataSource.

> DataSource configuration is controlled by external configuration
>   properties in spring.datasource.*. For example, you might declare the
>   following section in application.properties:
>
> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
> spring.datasource.username=dbuser
> spring.datasource.password=dbpass
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> ```

You can also configure a datasource in a @Configuration mapped class which implements EnvironmentAware.

JHipster generates a cool database configuration using HikariCP. You can check it out [the sample here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.java).

For Hibernate you can [configure JPA properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties). 
You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are `none, validate, update, create, create-drop`. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded (default create-drop) or not (default none).

For example to create and drop tables you can add the following to your application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

As for EntityManager when you EnableAutoConfiguration you will trigger a [JpaBaseConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java) which will create an entity manager for you.

You can also  use a custom EntityManagerFactory.

> To take full control of the configuration of the EntityManagerFactory,
>   you need to add a @Bean named ‘entityManagerFactory’. Spring Boot
>   auto-configuration switches off its entity manager based on the
>   presence of a bean of that type.

And btw you can also use a traditional persistence.xml

Comment: I already have it working. I can use spring repositories with MySQL (see the link to my prevoius post) What I want for now is pure Hibernate and EntityManager

Comment: It worked in a way now I have:                                                            Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory[org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@351e8433] instead of NullPointer and this is great!            One thing doesn't work though: when I call persist() nothing happens, I tried to call flush() afterwards but then I have:    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress. I also have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop

Comment: I think you might need @EnableTransactionManagement then.

Comment: It didnt work. However I also tried to use EntityTransaction and this is what I get:  "Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead", How about persistance.xml, I have it ready, just where to place it?

Comment: If you prefer to use persistence.xml then you need to define your own @Bean of type LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean (with id ‘entityManagerFactory’, and set the persistence unit name there. However i don't recommend that. Rather try and see why persist() does not work for you. I don't think changing to persistence.xml will change that.

Comment: And more than, why are you calling persist? Use CrudRepositories or JpaRepositories for what you need. You will need to configure them with @EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.repositories") (your repository packages)

Comment: I added @Transactional to the method where I have a call to persist() and I works:) For some reason every time i restart the application DB records from previous lunch are cleared out and I start with an empty DB. Any idea why? EDIT: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update does the trick:) also thanks for you help Laurentiu, I very much appreciate it!